# Как взять отдельно массив с другой таблицы MySql с помощи JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть проблема.
Есть товар, беру у него имя, описание, и другие данные.
И есть таблица с ценами, и у товара могут быть несколько цен.
И я хочу взять с помощи одного запроса сразу же название, имя, и массив с ценами.
Возможно ли это сделать?

Пробовал вот так: (Использую PDO библиотеку)

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id_product, name_product, min_description, 
        version, size, price
        FROM product INNER JOIN add_info_product using(id_product) INNER JOIN price using(id_product) WHERE id_product= :id");
        $sth->execute(array(
            ":id" => $id_product
        ));

        $product = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Тут я использую **fetchAll** а не просто **fetch**. Если я использую просто **fetch** то цена 1.
А если я использую fetchAll то цен например 2. Но тогда и id_product 2, и имя товара так-же 2. И я не знаю, правильно ли это.

Таблица price

| id_product | price |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1900 |
| 10001 | 1800 |

Пожалуйста! Подскажите мне. Подобные темы я не видел или не могу сформулировать вопрос что бы её найти.

Comment: Вариантов два. Первый - получить от MySQL отдельно одну цену на запись (cjjndtncndtyyj в нескольких записях один и тот же товар, но разные цены), а на PHP собрать цены одного и того же товара в массив. Второй - на стороне MySQL собрать все цены в один массив (СЫМ-список либо JSON-массив) и получить уже в таком виде. В любом случае не мешайте всё в кучу. Отдельно вопрос по тому, что должен сделать MySQL, и отдельно - по тому, что должен сделать PHP.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за ответ! И как я понял все таки одним запросом нельзя сделать то чего я хочу?
Думаю буду использовать первый вариант, так как я к этому почти уже пришел. Все таки спасибо за ответ. Сам я новичок, и много от кого слышу что обязательно делать все одним запросом. И вот с этого и возник у меня вопрос.

Comment: *И как я понял все таки одним запросом нельзя сделать то чего я хочу?* Странный Вы человек... я вроде открытым текстом говорю, что пока в принципе непонятно, что Вы хотите... думаете, с того времени что-то изменилось? нет, как было непонятно, так и осталось. Так что фиг знает, можно или нет... выберите хотя бы явно один из двух описанных мной вариантов, что ли.

Comment: @Akina спасибо конечно то что вы обратили внимание и как то пытаетесь помочь. Но получается и я вас не понял. В моем вопросе я сообщил о том что есть 2 таблицы, 1 таблица просто с информацией о товаре. Каждая строка - 1 товар соответственно. Есть 2 таблица, с ценами. Цен может быть несколько. И мне нужно 1 запросом вывести и товар(имя, описание ...) и массив с ценами. Я так понял вы не поняли как он должен выводится. В этом так-же и у меня есть вопрос но думаю мне нужен массив с данными и сразу же отдельным массивом внутри(ценами) `Не мешать все кучу` - видимо я из-за этого сделал такой вывод.

Comment: *И мне нужно 1 запросом вывести и товар(имя, описание ...) и массив с ценами.* Уффф. Запрос - это текст, текст задания, который составит программа на PHP и пошлёт серверу MySQL. В ответ сервер MySQL вернёт результат выполнения этого задания. Результат выполнения - это всегда плоская двумерная таблица (хотя в каждую отдельную ячейку хоть слона засунуть можно)... Вот я и хочу от Вас увидеть пример такого ответа в виде плоской таблицы, увидеть глазами то, что Вы хотите получить в ответ на посланный текст запроса. Как Вы потом это отобразите - мне пофиг.

Comment: @Akina понял теперь вас хорошо! Т.е вы разобрали 2 варианта без участия возможности использовать один запрос, при этом все же разобрали 2 варианта и образно вывели уже результат в ответе. Все таки вы разобрали их, так почему нельзя сделать тоже самое но 1 запросом? Вот и возник такой вопрос о том, вообще можно ли сделать это 1 запросом если вы все таки сообщили мне 2 варианта но не сообщили как это сделать 1 запросом. Если вам пофиг как я буду отображать данные то и должно быть пофиг как я их буду получать.  Вы хорошо умете объяснять, но все таки наверное я вас не правильно понял.

Comment: *вы разобрали 2 варианта без участия возможности использовать один запрос* o_O Каждый из этих вариантов (альтернативных - либо то, либо другое) предполагает, что от PHP к MySQL будет послано всего одно задание на выбор данных, т.е. один-единственный запрос. *почему нельзя сделать тоже самое но 1 запросом?* Одним. Одним-единственным. *Если вам пофиг как я буду отображать данные то и должно быть пофиг как я их буду получать.* Вопросом "как отобразить" займётесь после того, как что-то получите. Пока ещё не получено, так что не отвлекаемся.

Comment: @Akina, Все, спасибо вам теперь большое. Ваш второй ответ на мой первый, не очень понятно понял. Если что первым вариантом я изначально пользовался, вы ведь говорите о том что бы взять n раза один и тот же товар только с разными ценами? Каждая цена на каждый товар. Если это так то в моем выше проведенном вопросе я так и сделал. Если это хорошо, ну и вообще правильно, то я могу в принципе пользоваться этим вариантом. Сообщите, правильно ли я вас понял. Как отображать мне все равно как, поэтому принимаются любые варианты, главное что бы можно было сделать одним запросом.